# NodeJS to Mongo DB Atlas not connecting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm new to NodeJS and am having difficulties connecting to Mongo DB atlas.

app.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
require("dotenv").config();

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
          useCreateIndex:true,
}).then(() => {
          console.log("DB CONNECTED")
}).catch(() => {
          console.log("UNABLE TO CONNECT TO DB")
});
```

process.env

```
DATABASE = mongodb+srv://<DATABASE_NAME>:<DATABASE_PASSWORD>@cluster0.mzive.mongodb.net/? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Edit: I did add the database name and password in the slots <DATABASE_NAME> and <DATABASE_PASSWORD> I just swapped it out for the post.

Edit: The answer is "useCreateIndex:true" was the misbehaving code. I commented it out and it connected to the database, however I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

did you added database name that you wanted to be before question mark in the mongodb url

```
mongodb+srv://<DATABASE_NAME>:<DATABASE_PASSWORD>@cluster0.mzive.mongodb.net/{right here}? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Comment: Hi, I should have said, I put the database name and password and just replaced it for the post.

Comment: have you added the a name before the question mark in the url?  mongodb+srv://<DATABASE_NAME>:<DATABASE_PASSWORD>@cluster0.mzive.mongodb.net/{here}? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: Is that for the database name again?

Comment: yeah you need to give name there also for ex: if you want your database name to be Blog   then url should be mongodb+srv://<DATABASE_NAME>:<DATABASE_PASSWORD>@cluster0.mzive.mongodb.net/Blog? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority like this

Comment: Thanks, however, I did that with no luck, it didn't work, I did restart the server as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your name, password, and database in the URL

eg, if your database name is krishna and password is dev, and database name is a store

then URL will be

```
mongodb+srv://krishna:dev@cluster0.mzive.mongodb.net/store? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

you can find you username and password in from the mongo site.

Comment: Hi, I should have said, I put the database name and password and just replaced it for the post.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to write your **database** name in between / and ? like here /**{right here}**? in the conecction string URL

For example if your database name is LMS123 and Password is LMS@123 please do like follows... then it will be ok... ( Special charactors required to encode )

`MONGODB_URL =mongodb+srv://LMS123:LMS%40123@mangalalms.dfqso4m.mongodb.net/LMS123?retryWrites=true&w=majority`